# Not able to get the stringValue in arguments with SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

```
{
  "StatusResponse": 
  {
     "StatusCode": "000"
     "StatusDescription": "Operation Success(000)"
     "DebugDescription": "OperationSuccess"
  }-
"memId": "3e369fec-a9c5-418b-a950-0647f7e15d7c"
"token": null
"isAdmin": false
"isTeacher": false
"isParent": true
"kinderId": null
}
```

This is my JSON format

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "myURL").responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success(let data):
                let json = JSON(data)
                let memId = json["memId"].stringValue
                for result in json["StatusResponse"].arrayValue
                {
                    let code = result["StatusCode"].stringValue
                    print("code = \(code)")
                }
                print("memId : \(memId)")
            case .Failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
        }
```

I've one StatusResponse arguments in my code and others, however, I can get memId string value, any problem with my code why I can't get the StatusCode here?

Comment: StatusResponse is dictionary not arrayValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StatusResponse is dictionary not arrayValue, try this:

```
let code = json["StatusResponse"]["StatusCode"].stringValue
```

Comment: Thanks dude, but I change it without the if statement...it will have an error with if statement here. Thanks a lot

Comment: I edited the answer it works for me with if let when I replace stringValue to string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like StatusResponse is a dictionary in that JSON example, not an array.

EDIT: My Swift's a bit rusty right now, but here's what it should roughly look like:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "myURL").responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let data):
            let json = JSON(data)
            let memId = json["memId"].stringValue
            if let statusResponse = json["StatusResponse"] as? NSDictionary 
            {
                let code = statusResponse["StatusCode"].stringValue
                print("code = \(code)")
            }
            print("memId : \(memId)")
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: So is that possible way to get the stringValue of the StatusCode?

Comment: but NSDictionary cannot be cast from the JSON Xcode said that

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confuse with the JSON formatting. Whats the "-" after the third bracket?

if the JSON is like this:

```
{
  "StatusResponse": 
  {
     "StatusCode": "000"
     "StatusDescription": "Operation Success(000)"
     "DebugDescription": "OperationSuccess"
  },
"memId": "3e369fec-a9c5-418b-a950-0647f7e15d7c",
"token": null,
"isAdmin": false,
"isTeacher": false,
"isParent": true,
"kinderId": null
}
```

Then memId is not port of the StatusResponse object, therefore you should get the value by unwrapping it first (since it can be null).

```
guard let memId = json["memId"] as? String else {
    // manage case memId == null
}

print("My memId: \(memId)")
```

Hope this helps!